# Is it possible to reuse one shared managed object context beetween threads, when each thread can work with data not related to data in other thread?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, moc, managedobjectcontext

Simple example for the title question: one thread has prepared Place entity and is doing some processing on it (filling particular fields and their calculation takes time) and in the mean time the other thread has already prepared Category entity; the second "Category" thread wants to persist Category entity with *save:&error* causing Place entity from the first thread to be saved also while it didn't finished its processing job.

Am I right? Will I see the problem described if I use one shared moc?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not share `NSManagedObjectContext`s across threads. Do not share `NSManagedObject`s across threads. There really are no exceptions. Read [Concurrency with Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385) and apply the patterns it describes.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is possible and the method that you are looking for is:

`-(void)mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:(NSNotification *)notification;`

You have to create a different `NSManagedObjectContext` for each thread and all you have to do is to put your `NSManagedObjectContext` in the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` key in an `NSNotification` and register it to the default center. On its invokation perform `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification` on main thread and your changes will be merged each time you wil invoke the `save:&error` method.

Note: It has a little demerit, in my opinion, while fetching an object, it may belong to a different context (it will be nil after fetching) and if it does you have to fetch it differently:

`NSManagedObjectID *objectID = [YourObject objectID];`

`YourObject *copy =(YourObject*) [managedObjectContext objectWithID:objectID];`

Hope it helps. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385) is a link to better understand what I am saying.